# lateinit property locationRequest has not been initialized

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am following [raywenderlich's tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/230-introduction-to-google-maps-api-for-android-with-kotlin)  Introduction to Google Maps API for Android with Kotlin. All works as expected when the code is in an `Activity`, but when I put it into a `Fragment`, I get an error `lateinit property locationRequest has not been initialized`.

Here is my code:

XyzFragment.kt

```
package my.package.fragments

import android.content.IntentSender
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import my.package.R
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*
import java.io.IOException

class XyzFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private var locationUpdateState = false

    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
        private const val REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 2
    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?) = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xyz, container, false)

        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager?.findFragmentById(R.id.fGoogleMap) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this@XyzFragment.activity!!)

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)

        setUpMap()
    }


    private fun setUpMap() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@XyzFragment.context!!,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@XyzFragment.activity!!,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }

        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this@XyzFragment.activity!!) { location ->
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng)
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
            }
        }

        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(p0)

                lastLocation = p0.lastLocation
                placeMarkerOnMap(LatLng(lastLocation.latitude, lastLocation.longitude))
            }
        }

        createLocationRequest()
    }

    private fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)

        val titleStr = getAddress(location)
        markerOptions.title(titleStr)

        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }

    private fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng): String {

        val geocoder = Geocoder(this@XyzFragment.context)
        val addresses: List<Address>?
        val address: Address?
        var addressText = ""

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

            if (null != addresses && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                address = addresses[0]
                for (i in 0 until address.maxAddressLineIndex) {
                    addressText += if (i == 0) address.getAddressLine(i) else "\n" + address.getAddressLine(i)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("MapsActivity", e.localizedMessage)
        }

        return addressText
    }

    private fun createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 10000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 5000
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

        val client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this@XyzFragment.activity!!)
        val task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            locationUpdateState = true
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    e.startResolutionForResult(this@XyzFragment.activity,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                    )
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@XyzFragment.context!!,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@XyzFragment.activity!!,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
            return
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since `locationRequest` is just empty constructor initialization, then why not do `private val locationRequest = LocationRequest()`?

Comment: Works that way too. So no need for a late initialization of LocationRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locationRequest` is initialized in `createLocationRequest()`. This has to be done before the property is ever used elsewhere. In the tutorial, they call `createLocationRequest()` in `onCreate()`. In your Fragment, you should call it `onCreateView()` before you return the view.

Comment: You are right. Stupid mistake while copy-pasting my code from Activity to Fragment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

Please initialize **locationRequest** before using it.

**Approach 2:**

> private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest

could be changed to

> private var locationRequest: LocationRequest? = null

and use it by locationRequest?.someMethod()

Thank you